# How do sessions interact with each other?

Tags: 2013, development, user-controls, apps-development

I am writing a web app for SharePoint 2013 and am running into some interesting behavior.  Basically, I am making a series of web requests, but first need to store those in a `Dictionary` for use later.  However, if I open 3 tabs while debugging and hit them at the same time, I see the `Dictionary` object is not emptied and causes an exception when it tries to add the same endpoint multiple times.  Here is the relevant code of the app:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    protected static Dictionary<string, string> _endpoints = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear the lists of endpoints each time the page is loaded
        _endpoints.Clear();
        ...
        MethodThatAddsToDictionary();
       ...
    }

    public static void MethodThatAddsToDictionary()
    {
        ...
        _endpoints.Add(response.First(), response.Last());
    }
}
```

Debugging, sometimes `MethodThatAddsToDictionary()` is called twice before the `_endpoints.Clear()` is run at the top under the `Page_Load` event and I'll get an `ArgumentException` saying:

> an item with the same key has already been added

I feel like I'm missing something basic about the lifecycle of the app but haven't found anything that works so far.  I could wrap the `.Add()` in a conditional to check for the key before I add it, but I feel like that is a bandaid.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!